# How to find minimal polynomial of primitive element (field theory)

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, minimal-polynomials

I am given a primitive element $\alpha$ in the Galoisfield $F_{2^6}$. The question is to find the mimimal polynomial of $\alpha^7$. How to I find this?

My thoughts so far:
$$
\alpha^7 \rightarrow \alpha^2\\
\Rightarrow \alpha^7+ \alpha^2 = 0
$$
But it seems to simple to me...

Comment: A primitive element $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}_{2^6}$ has multiplicative order $2^6 - 1 = 63$, so $\alpha^7 \neq \alpha^2$.

Comment: Do you see that $\alpha^9=1$?

Comment: No why is $\alpha^9=1$? According to a theorem: $\alpha \in F_{q}: \alpha^{q-1} = 1$ so why 9?

Comment: Precisely what do you mean by “primitive element”? Do you mean a generator of the multiplicative group, which is the interpretation of @GerryMyerson, or do you mean an element $\alpha$ such that $k=\Bbb F_2(\alpha)$?

Comment: Definition of my textbook for primitive element:
$\alpha \in (F_{q}\backslash\{0\}: \forall a \in F_{q}\backslash\{O\}: a = \alpha^{m} , m \in \mathbb{Z} $

Comment: Sorry, I meant, if you let $\beta=\alpha^7$ (so $\beta$ is the element for which you want the minimal polynomial), then $\beta^9=1$.

Comment: Ok @GerryMyerson I see your implication with $\beta$. But isn't a minimal polynomial defined as a sum of k linear dependent terms:
$$
\alpha^k + l_{k-1}\alpha^{k-1} + \ldots + l_{1}\alpha + l_{0}
$$
Where k in this example is 7

Comment: No, the minimal polynomial for $\gamma$ is the monic polynomial $p$ of smallest degree such that $p(\gamma)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^9-1 = (x^3-1)(x^6+x^3+1)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$.

$\beta = \alpha^7$ is an element of order $9$ and thus a root of $x^9-1$.
It cannot be a root of $x^3-1$ and so must be a root of $x^6+x^3+1$.
So, the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ is $x^6+x^3+1$ or a divisor
thereof. Now, the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$
are $\beta$ and all its *conjugates,* that is, 
$\beta, \beta^2, \beta^{2^2}, \beta^{2^3}, \cdots$ are the roots
of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$. (Also, the minimal
polynomial of $\beta$ is *irreducible* over $\mathbb F_2$).
How many (distinct) conjugates are there?
What does that tell you about the degree of the minimal polynomial of
$\beta$? Can you deduce the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ from all this
information?

Comment: The way to show that $X^6+X^3+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$ is to observe first that any root of this polynomial is a primitive ninth root of unity; then to observe that you need to go all the way to $\Bbb F_{64}$ before you find any elements of multiplicative period $9$. Since the big field is of degree six over the little, your polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: How do you conclude that $\beta = \alpha^7$ is an element of order 9 and a root of $x^9-1$?

Comment: @brvh If $\alpha$ is an element of order $n$ (note: not just an $n$-th root of unity) by which we mean that $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $\alpha^n = 1$, then $\alpha^k$ is an element of order $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$. If you do not know this result, try to derive it for yourself and remember it for future use; it is very handy.

Comment: +1 The somewhat surprising part is that the answer is completely independent of the minimal polynomial of the given primitive element.

Comment: I think I get. I am just running into some trouble with showing that $x^6++x^3+1$ is irreducible. Can this be done via a shorter route than writing out a Cayley-table for $F_{2^6}$?

Comment: @brvh Did you write out the _conjugates_ of $\beta$ as I suggested? And did you _count_ them?  (See my revised answer).

Comment: I wrote down that $x^6+x^3+1$, if not irreducible can be written as the product of two polynomials of lower degree, $fg$ f and g could be both of degree 3 or one of degree 4 and the other of degree 2. From here I calculated the derived set of equations and became a contradiction, from which I could conclude that $x^6+x^3+1$ is irreducible. 

What exactly do you mean by a conjugate in this context?

Comment: If you are studying finite field theory and know about minimal polynomials but have no idea what conjugates mean, then I suggest you use the method suggested by Lubin in a comment on my answer. (Do you know about conjugates in the _complex field_ and that if an element $z \in \mathbb C$ is a root of $f(x)$, a polynomial with _real_ coefficients, then so is $z^*$ a root of $f(x)$?)